# Reduce frames on subplots

Tags: matplotlib, histogram, subplot

I have a couple great 8x8 Matrix Plots via subplot2grid.
It looks like:

```
plt.subplot2grid((6,7),(1+j,i))
plt.hist([0.5], 1, facecolor=c, alpha=1)
plt.axis('off')
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.001,wspace=0.001)
```

where c is a tuple generated from a colormap.

My Problem is that the Histogramm overlaps with the frame/margin of the subplot which causes black lines between the subplots.
How can I reduce these black lines i.e how can i reduce the frame/margins size of each subplot?

Thanks(:

Comment: Can you post a complete working example (keep it as simple as possible) that produces the problem you are having?

Comment: Yes i posted a working example

Comment: You should edit this question with a complete working example that someone can cut and paste and run in python. The example that you posted as a solution does not contain enough information to stand on its own. Generate some example data and make a complete example so that we can understand what the problem is.